# Which reporting tool would you recommend?

Tags: asp.net, reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best ASP.NET reporting engine with custom reports creation ability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006979/best-asp-net-reporting-engine-with-custom-reports-creation-ability)

Hi, I have some reporting functionality in my app and I want to improve it a bit. Its only SQL in a XML file which is read by some parser. There can be some params for that SQL and when its parsed and the params are injected, it is executed against my DB (SQL Server). I want to improve that a bit so that the results look better and are more flexible. This are the most important points I need to have:

- subtotals
- layout that can change dynamically according to settings in DB (like logo, slogan)
- possibility to use the same report template for several customers (same fields, but different logos,colors, slogans etc.)
- should run from an ASP.NET application

It should be as dynamic as possible. I know of Crystal Reports and the Microsoft Reporting Tool. Are there any others that might be of interest and are my above points possible at all?

Thanks for some ideas and hints :-)...

Answer (score 2):

We do all of this with [Sql Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx).  Since it uses Visual Studio to create it, the devs have no problem with creating reports.

Comment: +1 as the OP already has SQL, he also has SSRS.

Comment: Any book for that you would recommend?

Comment: I have not read it, but manning has never done me wrong:http://www.manning.com/updegraff/

Answer (score 0):

Dev Express Xtra Reports