# ASP.NET Reporting Tools (without MS SQL)

Tags: asp.net, reporting

I was given the task to create statistical reports and integrate them to an asp.net application (Webforms) connected to a MySQL DB.

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006979/best-asp-net-reporting-engine-with-custom-reports-creation-ability). However, the accepted answer is about SQL Reporting Services (I am using MySQL), and the most voted answer lists different tools (Crystal, ActiveReports, XtraReports Telerik, Versareports) but suggests they are all evolving and it was in 2009.

So, what options do I have at the present? Which one would you recommend me? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the quick and dirty, easy to use, and fairly flexible option, then ActiveReports still gets my vote. The most extensive is Crystal, but you have to really need the extra bang to warrant it's use, at least IMO. Telerik fits in between (if you are really familiar with their other UI controls, it is not a bad option, however, as the learning curve is greatly shortened).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I've been waiting to see if someone comes up with another suggestion. I've been also reading about Pentaho (www.pentaho.com), have you ever tried it? It looks like a powerful tool. Regards,

Comment: I have not tried Pentaho, but you will have to ask whether the subscription model is the best for your company. It looks like Pentaho is much more than just reporting, although that is the scenario in the video. Reminds me of SSRS.

Oh, by the way, something I missed in the response. SSRS can actually be used with sources other than SQL Server. I have not done it, but I have used SSRS with Oracle at one shop.