# how to get print button over here in website reportviewer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, crystal-reports, reportviewer, rdlc

in Report viewver in website im not getting the print option.

i have used

ReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton =true;

but still no print option came. how to get print button over here in website reportviewer in asp.net

Comment: have a look on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951009/sql-reporting-services-print-button-not-shown-in-mozilla

Comment: can you share the code to show the report?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not showing is because the print button is an Active X control - not supported by Firefox without any plugins.

If you are getting that issue under IE, check your security settings to see if Active X is getting blocked.