# Show entire report in SSRS Report Viewer Web Control?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer, multiple-browsers

So I have the SSRS Report Viewer Web control on a WebForm in my project, and it is working as expected now.

Since the print button does not naturally render in browsers other than IE, I've implemented this solution [SSRS print button in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4208457/97879) to give users in those browsers some ability to still print.

However, several of my reports are multi-page reports.  It would be useful to show the entirety of the report at one time so the user only has to click the print button one time.

I've looked for a setting in the control, and simply do not see one.  As I'm using server reports, it would not be possible to modify the RDL to make the page "larger".

What other approach could I take to display the whole multiple page report at one time?

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you want the interactive size to show ALL your data, but the normal printed output (via the SSRS button) to use the proper page size.

To do this, you can modify the report's **InteractiveSize Height** property and set it to zero (**0in**).  You can find this on the report's property page (press **F4** to see the property page if not displayed).  It is not shown in the normal report properties dialog -- only in the Properties Window.

This will make the interactive report page-less and render all the report data in one go.  Assuming its not terribly large, this works well for people annoyed by the paging on the interactive report viewer and who just want to scroll through a data list.

Comment: It's actually the other way around--In general, I want to keep the paging/printing as per normal.  It's only for the Chrome/Safari people that I'd like to show the whole thing.  Regardless, didn't know about that property--I'm assuming I can tie it to a parameter/expression though, which gives me all kinds of ideas.