# Display print button in Google Chrome

Tags: sql-server, google-chrome, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, report-viewer2010

I have a report in SSRS and I'm using chrome browser for open it but the print button don't show in chrome browser
and it is working in internet explorer. 
How  to show print button in report viewer using the plugin without the use of ASP code. I installed ActiveX for chrome browser but it is not displayed.
I need to enable print button for chrome and Firefox browser please help me.
(I'm using SQL 2012)

Comment: This has been answered before, please see this for your answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208457/ssrs-print-button-in-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: yes so there is not plugin method for this problem in chrome and firefox browser and all of methods for this problem are asp or php code in ssrs.