# no print button reporting service asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

[image: report page header without print button]

I am new to reporting services and I made a test page to view the report on click button event but I found that report viewer has no print button (printer icon) , so I need to display it how ?

```
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            DataTable DT = DA.selectFields("id,name", "nationalities", "");
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            LocalReport Report = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;


                Report.ReportPath = "Reports/Report1.rdl";
                Report.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportDataSource R_Ds = new ReportDataSource();
                               R_Ds.Name = "DataSet1";
                R_Ds.Value = DT;

                Report.DataSources.Add(R_Ds);
                Report.Refresh();
```

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome by any chance?

Comment: yes , and I tested now IE it is found

Comment: Thought so, it's a well known issue in anything other than Internet Explorer. There are a number of tutorials on the web about hacks to fix it.

Comment: Don't you know how to fix it sir ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS print button in Chrome and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208457/ssrs-print-button-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, the Print option for SSRS controls relies on ActiveX support within the browser. Most recent versions of popular browsers (e.g. Google Chrome, Edge, etc) no longer support ActiveX controls and thus, the print button.

In fact, older editions of Internet Explorer (< 10) may be the only ones that still support this.

Comment: FWIW, the print button is available in IE11 :)