# SSRS 2014 - Add print button in Report.aspx

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I'm using Reporting Services 2014 (SQL 2014 SP2 with CU1).

I would like to apply a workaround to enable a kind of print button on the report page when it is displayed on Chrome or Firefox.

I've seen some SO questions ([SQL Reporting Services - Print Button not shown in Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951009/sql-reporting-services-print-button-not-shown-in-mozilla)) and I know that print button, like the zoom button, is not officialy supported by SSRS.

I've seen these workaround and my question is: can I use these solutions on the Report.aspx page instead the ReportViewer.aspx? 
And in the Report.aspx where I put the code?

This is the only code of Report.aspx page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MSRS" Namespace="Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI" Assembly="ReportingServicesWebUserInterface" %>
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="Report.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportWrapperPage" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```