# Image and back color is not printing with Cross browser rdlc report printing with report viewer control in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, rdlc, reportviewer

to implement print feature for rdlc report in report viewer control in asp.net mvc web app, I followed this solution. It worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/14052577/870561.

this jquery script adds a print button in report viewer toolbar and on click shows a print preview dialogue that is cool. But it is **not adding images and back color styles in print.**

Please suggest a way to include images which are used in rdlc reports and also back colors. My code is attached below.

```
function pageLoad() {
    try {
        if (!$("#ff_print").length) {
            var ControlName = 'ReportViewer1';
            var innerTbody = '<tbody><tr><td><input type="image" style="border-width: 0px; padding: 2px; height: 16px; width: 16px;" alt="Print" src="/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=11.0.0.0&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.Print.gif" title="Print"></td></tr></tbody>';
            var innerTable = '<table title="Print" onclick="PrintFunc(\'' + ControlName + '\'); return false;" id="ff_print" style="border: 1px solid rgb(236, 233, 216); background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216); cursor: default;">' + innerTbody + '</table>'
            var outerDiv = '<div style="display: inline; font-size: 8pt; height: 30px;" class=" "><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display: inline;"><tbody><tr><td height="28px">' + innerTable + '</td></tr></tbody></table></div>';

            $("#ReportViewer1_ctl05 > div").append(outerDiv);
        }
    }
    catch (e) { alert(e); }

}

function PrintFunc() {
    var strFrameName = ("printer-" + (new Date()).getTime());
    var jFrame = $("<iframe name='" + strFrameName + "'>");
    jFrame
    .css("width", "1px")
    .css("height", "1px")
    .css("position", "absolute")
    .css("left", "-2000px")
    .appendTo($("body:first"));

    var objFrame = window.frames[strFrameName];
    var objDoc = objFrame.document;
    var jStyleDiv = $("<div>").append($("style").clone());

    objDoc.open();
    objDoc.write($("head").html());
    objDoc.write($("#VisibleReportContentReportViewer1_ctl09").html());
    objDoc.write("<style>@page { size: auto; margin:5mm } </style>")
    objDoc.close();
    objFrame.print();

    setTimeout(function () { jFrame.remove(); }, (60 * 1000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following points are taking effect 
1. CSS For back colors add css `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact`. [for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15253634/870561)
2. to print Images you need add this css property to img tag or div which contains the image. `display:block;` or `visibility:visible`
3. Chrome does not load images quickly, so you have to add pause before print. This hack worked for me.

The final solution I got this:

```
  function PrintFunc() {
        var strFrameName = ("printer-" + (new Date()).getTime());
        var jFrame = $("<iframe name='" + strFrameName + "'>");
        jFrame
        .css("width", "1px")
        .css("height", "1px")
        .css("position", "absolute")
        .css("left", "-2000px")
        .appendTo($("body:first"));

        var objFrame = window.frames[strFrameName];
        var objDoc = objFrame.document;
        var jStyleDiv = $("<div>").append($("style").clone());

        objDoc.open();
        objDoc.write($("head").html());
        objDoc.write($("#VisibleReportContentReportViewer1_ctl09").html());
        var style = "<style>";
        style = style + "@page { size: auto; margin: 0.845in 1in 0.845in 1in }";
        style = style + "@media print { body {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; } img{ visibility : visible; } }";
        style = style + "</style>";
        objDoc.write(style);

        setTimeout(function () {
            objDoc.close();
            objFrame.print();
        }, 750);

        setTimeout(function () { jFrame.remove(); }, (60 * 1000));
    }
```